# Indexing full text search queries for efficient fanout

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, full-text-search

While thinking about the design of various applications I might like to build some day, in several cases I have had a need to *fan out* a stream of incoming events based on whether or not they match a large selection of full text search queries provided by users.

A simple example of this problem is the implementation of a tool like Twitter streaming search: given many thousands of new tweets every second, efficiently select only the streaming subscribers whose search query is likely to match an incoming tweet.

A statement of the problem would be something like, "inverse full text search", where the full text is the query, and the search results are the search queries that would match that text.

For single term queries an implementation is obvious: simply tokenize the incoming document, then search a map of term->(list of subscribers), but things become more difficult when boolean queries are possible. In fact the problem is more general than full text search, but it is simplest understood in that context. There are many other examples where a large set of boolean terms need combined some way to optimize cost of evaluating them.

For example, imagine 3 search subscriptions:

1. Google AND Glass
2. Google AND Analytics
3. ((Glass AND Google) NOT Knol) OR Twitter

One possibility is to parse the query into a tree, then visit each node, extracting the term, and using the "map of term" approach, however this would require re-evaluating the subscribers query against the incoming document for each term. With enough subscribers, this is going to start getting slow very quickly.

Instead I am wondering if there is a well documented approach to rewrite the queries perhaps into a single query, where the result can be evaluated once, and tree nodes are annotated with a list of subscriber queries known to either exactly or almost certainly match any document that that point in the tree.

For example, the above queries might be rewritten so that a map of term->(query tree) exists, such as:

`Google -> (Analytics[2]
           Glass[1,3])
Twitter -> ([3])`

Is there any existing publicly documented system that does something like this? Ideally the solution would allow incrementally adding and removing subscribers, without some expensive step to rewrite the entire structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is with a simple dictionary that maps terms to queries. So given these four queries:

```
Query1: Google AND Glass
Query2: Google AND Analytics
Query3: ((Glass AND Google) NOT Knol) OR Twitter
Query4: Quick AND red AND fox
```

You build a dictionary, keyed by the term:

```
Google: Query1, Query2, Query3
Glass: Query1, Query3
Analytics: Query2
Knol: Query3
Twitter: Query3
Quick: Query4
red: Query4
fox: Query4
```

Now, consider a sentence like "The red glass on the knol is from Google."

Parse each word and look it up in the dictionary. For each word in the dictionary, add its list of queries to your master list of queries. Also, for every word that is found in the dictionary, add it to a hash table of relevant words. At the end of this step you'll have two structures: the list of queries to check, and the list of relevant words:

```
Queries list: Query1, Query2, Query3, Query4
Relevant words: Google, Glass, Knol, red
```

Now it's a matter of processing each query, checking to see if the words are in the relevant words list.

For Query1, for example, you'd check to see if the relevant words list contains Google and Glass.

The complexity of this isn't too bad. You have an O(1) lookup for each parsed word in the text. For each query identified during the parsing phase, you have some number, N, O(1) lookups against the relevant words hash table. There's some very small amount of logic involved in doing the Boolean evaluation, but most queries will be simple "all words" or "any word" type queries (i.e. "this AND that", or "this OR that").

The nice thing about this model is that it's pretty easy to farm out to multiple processors. You can parse the words in a single thread, pushing them to a concurrent queue. Multiple threads service that queue, doing the lookups and building their own lists of queries that need to be checked. When all those lookups are done, you merge the queries lists from the multiple threads and again put them on a concurrent queue that multiple threads can service.

Say you have a million queries, averaging five words each (which would likely be a big average). Absolute worst case here is that some text comes in that contains at least one word from each query. So you have a list of a million queries to check in pass 2. At worst, that's 5 million dictionary lookups.

The first pass of this algorithm is O(n), where `n` is the number of words in the incoming text. That will create a list of `k` queries. The second pass is O(km), where `m` is the average number of words per query.

The beauty of this approach is its simplicity, and it will perform well for moderately large numbers of queries, depending on the size of the text you're feeding it. There is a potentially faster way, but it's much more involved.

Rather than building a dictionary that maps terms to queries, you use a modified Aho-Corasick string search algorithm that is very similar to what the Unix `fgrep` program uses to match multiple regular expressions in a single pass over the text. The details of that are way beyond my ability to explain in a short note here. You might want to track down an old Dr. Dobb's Journal article called something like "Parallel Pattern Matching and fgrep", which as I recall had a reasonably good explanation of how this is done. (A quick search didn't find the article text, but you might have better luck.) You'll also want to read the original Aho-Corasick paper: [Efficient String Matching: an Aid to Bibliographic Search](http://www.win.tue.nl/~watson/2R080/opdracht/p333-aho-corasick.pdf). That discusses parallel pattern matching literal strings, but the basic idea works for matching regular expressions or Boolean search queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you can parse your query into boolean expressions, what you have is a set of rules, with the input variables the presence or absence of terms in the search text. For each search text you could use parsing + table lookup or Aho-Corasick to work out which terms are present and then use an implementation of the Rete algorithm such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drools to work out which rules to fire given that input.

(Alternately, you could batch up your input texts, build a small text search database from them, and then run your queries.  My guess is that this stops being stupidly inefficient when you can afford to wait long enough between query runs for the text search database size to be comparable with the size of the combined queries).